# Why adding H-gate is referred as changing the basis of measurement?

Tags: qiskit, textbook-and-exercises, measurement

I study Qiskit. When I measure a qubit by including `qc.measure(qb,cb)` instruction, I measure it in the computational basis. But if I apply the Hadamard gate adding `qc.h(qb)` before the measurement `qc.measure(qb,cb)`, it is often referred to as measuring in X-basis. In my mind measuring in a different basis should involve some changes in the measurement apparatus, not in the state of the system being measured (as happens in this case). I understand that computationally, applying the Hadamard gate produces the same outcome as the actual measurement in a different basis, but I'm just curious why it is call the 'change of basis'. Is it just some informal naming convention or does it have some hidden meaning?

Answer (score 2):

There are many ways to see that (one can invoke group theory, for example), but the way that I find easier is the following.

Let q denote a system of a single qubit. Consider then two situations:

1. q is in the state $| 0 \rangle$ or $| 1 \rangle $ and we measure q in the x-basis, $\{|+\rangle, |-\rangle\}$. Because $| 0 \rangle = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} (| + \rangle + | - \rangle)$ and $| 1 \rangle = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} (| + \rangle - | - \rangle)$, we get as outcome $| + \rangle$ with probability $1/2$ or $| - \rangle$ with the same probability.
2. q is in the state $| + \rangle$ or $| - \rangle $ and we measure in the standard basis, $\{|0\rangle, |1\rangle\}$. Because $| + \rangle = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} (| 0 \rangle + | 1 \rangle)$ and $| - \rangle = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} (| 0 \rangle - | 1 \rangle)$, we get as outcome $| 0 \rangle$ with probability $1/2$ or $| 1 \rangle$ with the same probability.

Now, note that if we define the map $H: |0\rangle \to |+\rangle, |1\rangle \to |-\rangle$, *situation 1 turns exactly into situation 2*! But note that the map $H$ is just the definition of the Hadamard gate. Therefore, the Hadamard gate makes the two situations equivalent.

**Obs 1.** Conversely, if the map was $H: |+\rangle \to |0\rangle, |-\rangle \to |1\rangle$ it would turn situation 2 exactly into situation 1. This can also be used as the definition of the Hadamard gate.

Answer (score 0):

Any unitary operator can be understood as a change of basis in which we describe operators in quantum theory.

Specifically, the Hadamard gate is a unitary that sends the basis $\{\vert 0\rangle , \vert 1\rangle\}$ into the basis $\{\vert + \rangle, \vert - \rangle\}$. If you note, we changed the eigenbasis of Z into the eigenbasis of X.